# What does the tilde symbol after an equals do?

Tags: matlab, symbols, arithmetic-expressions

What does the tilde symbol `~` do in Matlab?

for example, I've got the Matlab line, in which `a` and `b` are tables.

```
a =~b;
```

Comment: ~ is the operator for logical not

Comment: Type `help ~` and read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically `a` is assigned to the result of the logical not operator applied to `b`

For example if `b` is the matrix

```
b = [12 0 10]
```

then

```
a = ~b 
a = [0 1 0]
```

See http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/not.html for details

Comment: So , is the the same as this?: a = imcomplement(find(b));

Comment: @user3115590: no. If this works at all, it would be  a = imcomplement(b==0)